# Creating a difference column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with prices for several items.

```
items st.price b.price s.price
item1 10.50    8.00    12.00
item2  9.00    7.50    11.50
item3 22.00    20.00   25.00
item4 19.00    17.00   22.00
item5 55.00    53.00   57.00
```

I want to create a new column `difference` that indicates the difference of the highest price of the item and extract the sum of the other 2 prices.

```
EDIT: EXPECTED OUTPUT
    items st.price b.price s.price difference
    item1 10.50    8.00    12.00    -6.5
    item2  9.00    7.50    11.50    -5
    item3 22.00    20.00   25.00    -19
    item4 19.00    17.00   22.00    -14
    item5 55.00    53.00   57.00    -51
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be, we can use `apply` to get the `max` of each row and then subtract from the `sum` of the rest

```
df1$difference <- apply(df1[-1], 1, function(x) {
       i1 <- which.max(x)
      x[i1]- sum(x[-i1])})
```

---

Or using a vectorized option with `pmax` to get the `max` of each row, `replace` the numeric columns where the value is not equal to 'mx' with `NA`, apply the `rowSums` and get the difference between the 'mx' and this output

```
mx <- do.call(pmax, df1[-1])
mx  - rowSums(replace(df1[-1], df1[-1] == mx, NA), na.rm = TRUE)
#[1]  -6.5  -5.0 -17.0 -14.0 -51.0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(items = c("item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", 
"item5"), st.price = c(10.5, 9, 22, 19, 55), b.price = c(8, 7.5, 
20, 17, 53), s.price = c(12, 11.5, 25, 22, 57)), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```